# Unexpected token in variable name

Tags: r, token

I would like to recode a variable (`Pr(>|t|)_oldvar`) which contains a ">")

```
mydata$newvar[mydata$Pr(>|t|)_oldvar>0,10] <- 0
```

I get an error that there is an unexpected '>'.

I get the same error when I try to rename the variable.

Any idea's on how to get the '>|t|' out of the variable name?

Comment: You could index it as a string - `mydata["Pr(>|t|)_oldvar"]`

Comment: Most of the time you encounter that name it is a matrix column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be too simple of an approach, but have you tried using the names function? Something like the following: `names(mydata)[which(colnames(mydata)=="Pr(>|t|)_oldvar")] <- "Pr_newvar"`

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and please [edit] your post.